# How to figure out the maximal solution to an ODE?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

So I know that the maximal solution to an ODE is the biggest interval where the solution is defined, but imagine you are working with this DE:

$$
x(t)\frac{dx}{dt}=4t
$$
To solve this I used the separable variables method where the IVP was defined as $$x(t_0)=x_0$$
$$
x(t)\sqrt{4t^2-4t_0^2+x_0}
$$

Now I went to check where this solution is valid, which led me to $$t\geq\frac{\sqrt{x_0-4t_0}}2$$
But now at the same time I have to take in consideration that $$t_0\leq\frac{x_0}{4}$$

How do I find the maximal solution, with all this information?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $x(t) = \sqrt{4t^2 - 4t_0^2 + x_0^2}$? (for $x_0\geq 0$)?

Comment: $\frac 12\frac{d}{dt}x^2 =2 \frac{d}{dt}t^2$ then $x = \pm\sqrt{4t^2+C_0}$ and $x(t_0) = x_0$ defines $C_0$

Comment: Yes but I wanted to know which what is the greatest interval in which the solution is valid